# Binomial coefficients modulo square of a prime

Tags: c++, math, binomial-coefficients

Calculate the binomial coefficient: \binom{852 467 439}{426} (nCk) modulo 289

I has used this document: [https://web.archive.org/web/20170202003812/http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20170202003812/http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/%7Eandrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf)

```
int VpnCk(int n, int k, int p){
    int res = 0, t = p;
    while (n > t){
        res += (n/t - k/t - (n-k)/t);
        t *= p;
        if (res == 2) break;
    }
    return res;
}
```

So nCk is divided by 17, but 289 
Use **vector** to get Representation of N, K, N-K in base 17.

```
vector<unsigned long long> getRepresentation(unsigned long long N, int mod) {
    vector<unsigned long long> res;
    while (N > 0) {
        res.push_back(N % mod);
        N /= mod;
    }
    return res;
}
...
int main(){
    ...
    n17.resize(n17.size()+1);
    k17.resize(n17.size()); r17.resize(n17.size());
}
```

N:   8   5  10  10   6   5   1   2   0
K:   1   8   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
N-K: 7  14   8  10   6   5   1   2   0

**Define:** 
N = n_0 + 17 * n_1 + ... + 17^d * n_d (the value of n_i has listed)
N_i = n_i + 17 * n_{i+1} (i=0,d)

So, (N_i)!/(K_i)!(R_i)! modulo 289 are: 1 42 141 1 1 1 1 1
And

```
unsigned long long C289(unsigned long long N, unsigned long long K, unsigned long long R){
    if (K > N) {
        return 1;
    }
    return (((fact17[N] * binpow(fact17[R], 271, 289)) % 289) * binpow(fact17[K], 271, 289)) % 289;
}
```

```
int v17 = VpnCk(N, K, 17);
if (VpnCk(N, K, 17) == 2) res3 = 0;
else {
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i <= k17.size()-2; ++i){
        res3 = (res3 * C289(n17[i+1]*17 + n17[i], k17[i+1]*17 + k17[i], r17[i+1]*17 + r17[i])) % 289;
    }
    if (v17 == 1) res3 = (res3*17) % 289;
}
cout << res3;
```

**My answer is 102, but the correct answer is 238. What's wrong in my code**

P/s: can I use Latex on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Evg Ok, I will edit my post now.